# Delete duplicates from `MySQL` and keep single record

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to find duplicate records and have verified it runs correctly.

```
SELECT MLS_LISTING_ID, STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, MLS_ID, SALE_PRICE, ZIP_CODE, TLN_REALTOR_ID, COUNT(mls_id)
FROM idx_FM_BO_NA
GROUP BY TLN_REALTOR_ID, STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, SALE_PRICE
HAVING COUNT(distinct MLS_ID) > 1;
```

How do I alter this query to delete duplicates so that there is only one instance of the record? I don't worried which record(s) get deleted, but I need one of them to stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer is correct:

```
delete from table1 USING table1, table1 as vtable 
WHERE table1.ID<vtable.ID AND table1.field_name=vtable.field_name
```

The only difference between this one and paulsm4's answer that the ids are compared using less-than rather than not-equals. That way, later are not compared with earlier records (which means that one and only one of the identical records will be kept). I tested this out with my own data that I needed this for, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-removing-eliminating-duplicates-from-a-mysql-table/

```
delete from table1 USING table1, table1 as vtable 
WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID) AND (table1.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

> 1. Here you tell mysql that there is a table1.
> 2. Then you tell it that you will use table1 and a virtual table with the values of table1.
> 3. This will let mysql not compare a record with itself!
> 4. Here you tell it that there shouldn’t be records with the same field_name.

Comment: so in my example ID would be TLN_REALTOR_ID and I would keep adding field_name with AND for the rest to emulate the GROUP BY?  Will this delete all duplicates or leave one instance?

Comment: I believe this will *not* keep a single record, but instead delete all rows that have duplicates (including their duplicates). I'm guessing the reason for this is that the first row is compared with the second row (which obviously don't have the same ids), but then the second row is compared with the first row.. and so both are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> The following MySQL commands will create a temporary table and
>   populate it with all columns GROUPED by one column name (the column
>   that has duplicates) and order them by the primary key ascending. The
>   second command creates a real table from the temporary table. The
>   third command drops the table that is being used and finally the last
>   command renames the second temporary table to the current being used
>   table name.

Thats a really fast solution.
Here are the four commands:

1. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE videos_temp AS SELECT * FROM videos GROUP by
   title ORDER BY videoid ASC;`
2. `CREATE TABLE videos_temp2 AS SELECT * FROM videos_temp;`
3. `DROP TABLE videos;`
4. `ALTER TABLE videos_temp2 RENAME videos;`